# How to change background using jquery slider?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-slider

I am using jquery slider, i have a single layout and a center div for content..i need to change the color of the layout while i slide on a different page. This is What i am doing using asp.net mvc3.

HTML:

```
<div id="iPhone_Product">
        <div class="slides_containeriphone" >
            @if (Model == null)
            {
                <div class="animateriphone" id="1">
                    @Html.Partial("_iPhone_Main")
                </div>
                    <div class="animateriphone" id="2">
                    @Html.Partial("Salah")
                </div>
                    <div class="animateriphone" id="3">
                    @Html.Partial("_Tasbeeh")
                </div>
            }
            else
            { 
                foreach (string s in Model)
                {
                    <div class="animateriphone">
                        @Html.Partial(s);
                    </div>
                }
            }

        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
function color_change() {

        var x = document.getElementById('2');

        if (x.id == '2') {
            $(".st_tabs_container").css({ "background-color": "#ffe21f" })
        }
        else
        {
            $(".st_tabs_container").css({ "background-color": "#c8c7c7" })
        }
    }
```

It changes the background to #ffe21f but the else statement does not work.
Any help would be appericiated.

Answer (score 0):

You just create the object of

```
var x = document.getElementById('2');
```

so **x.id** always has the value **2**. so that your if condition will always return **true**

Try simple javascript

```
       var color = document.getElementById('some').style.backgroundColor;
```

the variable **color** has the value. 
if your current background is red the **color = rgb(255, 0, 0)";**
then chech the **color** variable to change your background

eg:

```
if(color == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
  {
      document.getElementById('some').style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
  }
  else 
  {
      document.getElementById('some').style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
  }
```

Comment: it should change the background and then again change it during sliding...ist is yellow and then gray...

Comment: the value of **x.id** always be the same. ie x.id=2. Thats why if condition always satisfy.

Comment: if you look at the code there are 3 slides "_iPhone_Main" " salah" and "tasbeeh" only one has the color "ffe21f" and the other two have"c8c7c7". i am so weak in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
idArray = ['1', '2', '3'];

        for (var item = 0; item < idArray.length; item++) 
        {

            var x = document.getElementById(idArray[item]);
        }

        if
                (x.id == '2') {
            $(".st_tabs_container").css({ "background-color": "#ffe21f" })
        }
        else
        {
            $(".st_tabs_container").css({ "background-color": "#c8c7c7" })
        }
```